# Skip line with a specific string from a file - Batch script

Tags: file, batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to copy part of abc.txt to def.txt file using windows batch scripting.

abc.txt

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 
11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production. With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage
Management, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
... exporting table             table_1      2000 rows exported
..... exporting table             table_2        456512 rows exported
. . exporting table             table_3   So on...
Export successful with warnings. table_1 has some issue.
```

def.txt

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 
11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production. With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage
Management, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
Export successful with warnings. table_1 has some issue.
```

In short I want to skip the lines that are having the string "exporting" and move the result to def.txt. I tried using `for /F` but could not acheive this. Could you please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. findstr /v works perfect for me. But if I want to remove dots alone "..." irrespective of number of dots from abc.txt. Is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findstr /v /c:"exporting" abc.txt > def.txt
```

No need to iterate over the file. Just filter the lines in the input file that does not match (`/v`) the condition of containing the indicated literal, and send the output to the indicated file.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    > def.txt (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:. " %%a in ('
            findstr /n "^" abc.txt
        ') do echo(%%b
    )
```

Here the file is processed by `findstr` to number the lines (to preserver empty lines in source file), the output processed by a `for /f` command  with  `delims` and `tokens` clauses configured to remove starting spaces/dots/colons in output lines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. findstr /v works perfect for me. But if I want to remove dots alone "..." irrespective of number of dots from abc.txt. Is there a way?

Comment: @SwaroopNarasimha, If you only want to remove the dots, then you will need to iterate the file. See updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This not effectively different from MC ND's solution - it's another option though:  It's case sensitive at the moment but has a `/i` switch to change that.

```
find /v "exporting" < abc.txt > def.txt
```